# Library tags and language tag uses

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, specific-site

I recently earned the gold [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) badge, and I am shooting for the gold [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) badge, but I have only about 600 upvotes in the latter.  This makes me wonder:

At what point does a question reach the threshold for when it should be tagged for a language library, only the language, or both?

For example, I have seen questions that do not include any jQuery code at all (although they may include some JavaScript code), but the OP has used [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) because a jQuery solution is acceptable to them.  If there are no answers that use jQuery, should the tag be removed.  What if there are, but the accepted answer does not?  What if only jQuery methods are used in the solution?  Should [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) be removed in that case?

I am mostly wondering at what point it becomes acceptable to retag [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) questions with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).  I can see how this could apply to other sets of tags as well such as [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), or [php](/questions/tagged/php) and some frameworks. Does Stack Overflow have a standard for this? Can it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we have a standard, but here's my 2¢:

If you have a question that is general to the language, such as *How do I change the text in a `<div>`?*, only tag for the language (so tags like [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [html](/questions/tagged/html), [dom](/questions/tagged/dom)) even if, say, a jQuery solution is acceptable.

Only if you have a question about a framework should you tag for the framework, but *you should still tag for the language*. Especially for smaller frameworks that aren't jQuery or Rails, this is necessary for the question to be found. If the question is solely about the framework, and doesn't include and of the language, you can tag with only the framework.

Comment: But how can the question about the framework not include any of the language if the framework is written in the language?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: It's certainly rare, but here's two examples where I think it's correct (Cocoa is the framework, Objective-C the relevant langugage): [Sharing an NSArraycontroller between multiple views in separate nib files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5477144), [When an NSWindow object has a delegate that is a NSWindow subclass who is responsible...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5327847). These _could_ be tagged with [tag:objective-c], but I'd say when discussing the framework from a "design" level it's not completely appropriate.